# В заданный непустой текст могут входить только цифры и буквы. Определить, есть ли текст десятичной записи числа кратного 9

Tags: python, python-3.x

В заданный непустой текст могут входить только цифры и буквы. Определить, есть ли текст десятичной записи числа кратного 9.

Comment: Найти в непустом тексте все числа и проверить каждое на делимость на 9.

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос более понятно

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = re.findall(r'\d+', 'a58g928gdf9sdf81fsdjh36')
for i in range(len(a)):
    if int(a[i]) % 9 == 0:
        print(a[i])
```

Comment: мне кажется автор имел в виду нечто другое

Comment: @finally Я не собираюсь писать ему всю домашку. Числа делящиеся на девять у него все есть, пусть теперь сам думает.

Comment: так я и не говорю помогать) ясное дело, когда автор вопроса не прикладывает свои попытки желание отпадает.. мне лично кажется, что надо уже помочь, либо ничего не делать

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica, нет тут числа.

Comment: @finally Ахах, ну тогда у нас либо не будет программистов, либо будут глупые ) нужно помочь так, чтобы человек сам мог подумать.

Comment: А, стоп. `findall` не заметил. Значит числа есть, но не те)

Comment: @Qwertiy Не понимаю про что вы, какие не те числа )))

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica, я вопрос понимаю так, что ему надо любую подстроку подходящую найти, т. е. при входной строке `aaa1b2c1271` ответ "да" с фрагментом `27`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ага, я понял. Ну тогда в тупую двойной цикл.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102218/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ver-nick-says-reinstate-monica).

Comment: @Ver Nick says Reinstate Привет! Приглашаю принять участие в [Новогодний конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1061127/28748)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Спасибо!